# how may i add bios&firmware updates into the FreeDOS 1.3-RC4 live .iso?

Tags: iso-image, livecd, freedos

So far i've downloaded the FreeDOS 1.3-RC4 live iso, mounted it, copied the contents, added some files, and created a new bootable iso using this command:

```
genisoimage -no-emul-boot -boot-info-table -boot-load-size=4 -cisolinux/boot.cat -bisolinux/isolinux.bin -o../'freedos live EliteDesk 800 G1 bios&IME firmware'.iso .
```

(That's genisoimage:amd64 (9:1.1.11-3.1ubuntu1) in lubuntu 20.04.)

When i mount the new .iso, linux can clearly see that within games i've added diaguefi/setup.exe:

```
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root     2048 2021-06-13 Sun 20:10:29 /mnt/fr/games/diaguefi/
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 50381636 2020-10-06 Tue 13:14:50 /mnt/fr/games/diaguefi/setup.exe*
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root     2048 2021-04-30 Fri 08:43:15 /mnt/fr/games/flpybird/
-r-xr-xr-x 1 root root     8704 2021-03-18 Thu 13:16:27 /mnt/fr/games/flpybird/flpybird.com*
```

But when i boot it (via grub using memdisk), only the original content appears:

```
R:\GAMES>dir
 Volume in drive R is FD13-RAMDRV
 Volume Serial Number is 0616-0921
 Directory of R:\GAMES

.                   <DIR>  06/16/2021  9:21a
..                  <DIR>  06/16/2021  9:21a
FLPYBIRD            <DIR>  06/16/2021  9:21a
         0 file(s)             0 bytes
         3 dir(s)    375,037,952 bytes free
R:\GAMES>
```

Why doesn't FreeDOS see the content i've added?  What do i need to do?

Comment: If the bios update is not designed for a dos environment you cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When freedos boots up on the iso created above,

Drive R: is the current drive, and it's contents apparently match what was on the original FreeDOS 1.3-RC4 live .iso, and

Drive E: contains the contents of the new .iso that i've created and booted.

Comment: If this is the answer, write it like an answer and not another question. Then you can select it with the green checkmark on the left. You get points for answering your own questions.